# How to solve in flutter fonts_asset_mainfest?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-fonts

```
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'google_fonts' in 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'.
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/asset_manifest.dart:7:8: Error: Not found: 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'
import 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart' as google_fonts_asset_manifest;
       ^
Unhandled exception:
Null check operator used on a null value
#0      IncrementalJavaScriptBundler.compile (package:frontend_server/src/javascript_bundle.dart:227:69)
#1      FrontendCompiler.writeJavaScriptBundle (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:778:46)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:641:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1308:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
Finished with error: the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Failed to compile application.
```

Could you please help me? My work has been delayed for a few days

I do this process

- cmd: **Flutter clean**
- cmd: **Flutter pub get**
- cmd: **Fultter packages get**

But here it's not work place help me **

> **[[Error show here....]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4EiO.png)**

Comment: paste your pubspec.yaml

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you are added `google_fonts: latest_version` in ***pubspec.yaml*** file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_fonts: ^replace_with_latest_version
```

- If not available:
  Run the following command in the project directory:

```
flutter pub add google_fonts
```

or add a line like this to your package's ***pubspec.yaml*** (and run an implicit flutter pub get)

```
dependencies:
  google_fonts: ^5.1.0
```

- You can also check the reports/issues on GitHub regarding the package, here is the link:
  [google_fonts GitHub Issues](https://github.com/material-foundation/flutter-packages/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22p%3A+google_fonts%22)

Comment: Let me know if everything is fine & still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but with other packages
I solved my problem by opening the Android folder and syncing Gradle again